# MVC3 Consuming java web services only works with ip address

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I am calling a java web service from my Asp.net MVC web application. The web service works if the endpoint address in the web.config references the server with its ip address or localost. But when i replace the ip adderess with the host name it can not find the server.

Here is the service section of my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="TestInterfaceBeanServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://MyServer:8080/ets-impl-2.0/TestInterfaceBean"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestInterfaceBeanServiceSoapBinding"
      contract="TestService.TestInterfaceBean" name="TestInterfaceBeanPort" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the machine you are running this on can resolve MyServer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the URL ( `http://MyServer:8080/ets-impl-2.0/TestInterfaceBean` ) in a browser.  Is the host resolved correctly?

You could use `nslookup myserver` to find out if the servername is being resolved to the same IP address you are expecting it to be.

Comment: I've verified i can access the wsdl ina browser. I've also tried verified the ip address and tried using the full hostname brought back by nslookup.

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you deploy to production in the DMZ and are accessing an internal web service.  Your DMZ server is likely not using the internal DNS so it doesn't know how to resolve the IP Address.

We've solved this in the past by adding the server name & ip address to the Windows Hosts file.

Comment: I have two test servers. One is on the same box as the client. I have added both machines to the host file. Also all the machines are on our internal network.